# Calling a method every hour

Tags: c#, timer

I am setting number of hours to download something and comparing it with the current time to achieve my task. For an example, If I have set up my task for 48 hours then I am comparing it with current time and getting expected results. In this situation after completion of 48 hours I am calling another method.

**Here is my code:**

```
 if (_ScheduledTweetCount > 0 || DateTime.Now <= _ScheduledTweetHourTxtBox)
    {
        if (_ScheduledTweetCount > 0)
        {
            _ScheduledTweetCount--;
        }
        else
        {
            _ScheduledTweetHourTxtBox.CompareTo(scheduledTweetHourTxtBox);    
        }
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
    }
  CallingAnotherMethod();
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is, instead of waiting 48 hours to call the `CallingAnotherMethod();` method, I want to call it on every hour until it reaches my scheduled time. I saw some article related timer but I am not sure in this scenario how can I use it.

Comment: Are you using a console application or a form application? i don´t know exactly what you want.

Comment: what issues are you having.. can you be more specific..

Comment: Sorry, but there is not enough code/information here to help you.

Comment: Yes, timers are great for this. What is your question?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET : Let's say if you put request for 2 days(48 hours) then my code will run till 2 days and then call another method. What I want is, instead of collecting info for next 48 hours, I want to see how much data is collected in one hour and call another method. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you would have a 1 hour timer that invokes the method and a counter that counts up to 48 before calling the final method. Still not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing method every hour on the hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291816/executing-method-every-hour-on-the-hour)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this. One is by using a timer that runs every 60 minutes from when it was first called. The second is by creating a timer that runs in the background and gets called every 10 seconds or so that will check if an hour has passed (e.g. if the time has changed from 2.55 to 3.10).

**60 minute timer**

```
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60 * 60 * 1000); //one hour in milliseconds
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(everyHour);
myTimer.Start();
```

Event Handler Method:

```
private static void everyHour(object src, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // Put the code you want repeated in here
}
```

**Check if the time has changed by an hourly value**

```
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);   //One second, (less of an interval means that it will be more accurate, but more of an interval will mean that it uses less resources.  
int previousHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(everyHour);
myTimer.Start();
```

Event Handler Method:

```
private static void everyHour(object src, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     if(previousHour < DateTime.Now.Hour || (previousHour == 23 && DateTime.Now.Hour == 0))
     {
           previousHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
           YourMethod(); // Call The method with your important staff..
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your timer interval to 30000 (30s) and put this
code to your timer tick:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
      {
           // Do something
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I published an answer for similar question [hree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692176/2441637), just re-writing the code here, as some people may not like reading the answer that does not have code lines:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COREserver{
    public static partial class COREtasks{   // partial to be able to split the same class in multiple files
        public static async void RunHourlyTasks(params Action[] tasks)
        {
            DateTime runHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(runHour.Hour, 0, 0);  // ensure minutes and seconds to be ZERO
            runHour = runHour.Date + ts;


            while (true)
            {
                TimeSpan duration = runHour.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                if(duration.TotalMilliseconds <= 0.0)
                { 
                    Parallel.Invoke(tasks);
                    runHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0);
                    continue;
                }
                int delay = (int)(duration.TotalMilliseconds / 2);
                await Task.Delay(30000);  // 30 seconds
            }
        }
    }
}
```