# Windows Services - Export a data to excel

Tags: c#, windows

Need query to download a data(stored procedure result) in excel through window services application. this service need to a schedule in system and download the data in server.

Please help!!!

Thanks..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Using window service - export a data to excel. I need a sample c# code for this..

Answer (score 0):

To export to excel, you need to either use office interop libraries or just convert the datatable (result from stored procedure) to a csv file.

Set this process up to execute automatically upon opening the application and save to a predetermined path (Ideally you save the path in the database you you can change it anytime you want)

Once all this is done, take the exe and schedule it with windows scheduled tasks.

EDIT:
As you are using windows services; you can make a background timer to check the time every 15 or 30 minutes and executes the process at a certain time

Comment: can you send any screen shot or sample code for this process

Comment: I don't have any myself... check msdn for interop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291816/executing-method-every-hour-on-the-hour check this for executing the task every hour or whenever... please you need to help yourself if you want others to help you... I'm not going to do your job for you